# Flutter command closes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

I downloaded flutter and decompress it to to C:/csr/flutter and out the bin folder in the variable environment. On the command prompt big I type flutter the command prompt closes.
I have tried many time the same problem is what I am experiencing, please what could be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`flutter` alone is not a command, try with `flutter doctor` or `flutter pub version`.

You can check all of flutter commands in this article. [Article](https://clasicwebtools.com/articulos/programacion/comandos-flutter.html)

Even Though, your question is not clear, try explaining your problem a bit more in depth.

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

add this path to your System Environment Variable